# The constructed object of type xxx is incompatible with the descriptor's return type: T

Tags: java, generics, java-8, collectors, supplier

I am trying to build a Collector class that will summarize my results into a TreeMap.  I am having trouble using a generic type for the accumulator/results.  The problem occurs in the definition of my supplier method.

My class currently looks like this:

```
public class CollectExclusions<T> implements Collector<CellList, T, T> {

    @Override
    public Supplier<T> supplier() {
        return TreeMap<String, ArrayList<String>>::new;
    }

    public static <T> CollectExclusions<T> toExclusionsSet() {
        return new CollectExclusions<>();
    }
}
```

And I invoke it as follows:

```
TreeMap<String, ArrayList<String>> exclusions = board.getWords().stream()
    .collect(CollectExclusions.toExclusionsSet());
```

Where in my class do I need to specify the type of the accumulator/result (T) to keep the class as generic as practical and how do I specify the type in the supplier?

Comment: What kind of results are you sumarizing?  What does your Collector do exactly?

Comment: If yo'ure expecting it to return a `TreeMap<String, ArrayList<String>>`, then at least the third type parameter (currently `T`) needs to be `TreeMap<String, ArrayList<String>>`.

Comment: CellList is an ArrayList of objects,  The accumulator is inspecting the objects and adding 0..* entries into the TreeMap result, based on various rules.

Comment: There is no practical reason to ever implement `Collector` manually. You can simply call `Collector.of(…)`, specifying the three or four functions. But regardless of that, when your supplier produces a `TreeMap`, you can not declare it to be an arbitrary `T`. We can’t tell you what your exact requirements are, as long as only you know, how your accumulator and combiner look like.

Comment: I was able to use a generic of TreeMap<K, V> instead of T.  After getting it working, I then refactored it to use Collector.of(...), and this reduced the size by about 25%.  Thanks all.